# Добавить uri param для GET-контроллера в приложении на flask-restplus

Tags: python, rest, flask, swagger

Хотел бы добавить добавить uri parameter для GET-контроллера.

Полностью код доступен [здесь](https://gist.github.com/dealenx/258d6e496935ea213b4ae614ab0f8971) (пример взят из оф. репозитория flask-restplus)

Есть модель:

```
todo = api.model('Todo', {
    'id': fields.Integer(readOnly=True, description='The task unique identifier'),
    'task': fields.String(required=True, description='The task details'),
    'is_deleted': fields.Boolean(required=True, description='The task delete condition', default="False"),
})
```

Необходимо получить все записи, где `is_deleted`== False.

Как реализовать GET-контроллер, чтобы можно было получить эти записи по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:5000/todos?is_delete=false`, а также можно было бы через swagger выполнить этот запрос, указав поле "is_delete" (сейчас отсутствует поле):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какую аннотацию необходимо написать, чтобы была такая возможность?

```
@ns.route('/')
class TodoList(Resource):
    '''Shows a list of all todos, and lets you POST to add new tasks'''
    @ns.doc('list_todos')
    @ns.marshal_list_with(todo)
    def get(self):
        '''List all tasks'''
        return DAO.todos

    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете посмотреть здесь. Возможно будет полезно для Вас!
https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/146

UPD:

Получилось реализовать с помощью аннотации @ns.param:

```
    @ns.doc('list_todos')
    @ns.marshal_list_with(todo)
    @ns.param('is_delete')
    def get(self):
        is_delete = request.args.get("is_delete", default=None)
        '''List all tasks'''
        return DAO.todos
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Сейчас подправлю ответ